# Listing grid fields as a relationship choice

Tags: relationships, grid

I'm building a site for a legal firm and I'd like to have each practice area display the lawyers that handle that type of law.

For example, if you went to the page that dealt with business law, it would list the 2-3 attorneys that specialize in that area of law.

Currently, I have a channel that handles the list of legal staff. This channel has a channel entry that has a Grid field with three columns... name, headshot and bio.

On the entry pages for the "practice area" pages, I have a Wygwam field for content and a Relationship field I'd like to connect to the channel entry that contains the staff Grid field.

Right now, when I connect the relationship field to the channel entry (staff listing), all I see in the select box for the Relationship field is the name of the channel entry.

Is it possible to have a relationship that lists the individual grid rows?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll be able to solve it this way. The intent of relationships is to relate **Channel Entries** together, not relate different data points in a specific entry to another entry.

I would recommend making a staff channel where each member has their own channel entry. That allows for way more leeway in what you're trying to do; It's also how I've seen every "staff listing" style implementation in any EE site I've built or worked on.

Comment: That is what I had thought about doing, but the nice thing about a grid is that they can easily re-order the output of the "staff listing" page by dragging/dropping the grid rows.

Comment: Go to Low: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-reorder That will take care of that issue. If you don't wanna spend, the easy way to handle it, which allows for a lot of leeway, is to set your `entry_date`s as a way of ordering your entries.